# Django, Python, Javascript database issue

Tags: javascript, python, django, database

I'm trying to create a user system where the user can save a list of their favourite bike racks. I've been using dummy users, but now I'm trying to integrate facebook log to actually create users as you log in. The issue is, even though I'm getting all the right information (console logs have proved this) when I try and add the user to the database through Django it fails. The following is the javascript code that calls django.

```
function addToFavorites(address, number, l, lon){
    alert("Added to favorites!");
    console.log("got to addToFavorites "+ user);
             $.ajax({
    url:'/racks/fave/',
    type: "POST",
    data: {address: address, number: number, lat:l, lon:lon, user:user,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}'
    },
```

The console.logs above are printing the correct thing. This calls the following code:

```
def add_favorite(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    addUser(request.POST.getlist('user')[0])
    u = request.POST.getlist('user')[0]
    address = request.POST.getlist('address')[0]
    number = request.POST.getlist('number')[0]
    lat = request.POST.getlist('lat')[0]
    lon = request.POST.getlist('lon')[0]
    addFavRack(u, address, number, lat, lon)
```

which in turn calls addUser:

```
def addUser(user):
u = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)[0]
u.user = user
u.save()
return u
```

Comment: Please indent your python code correctly.

Comment: What does "it fails" means in details?

Comment: 1. Please add error trace.
2. whats's the input user type for addUser function. Is it string?
3. If you are creating new user, in that case you've to first add new user to django. Use that user instance to create new UserProfile and then return the same. The addUser function does exactly opposite. the user input it expects is of User instance, not string.